# How can I drop all indexes in a SQL database with one command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, how can I drop all indexes in a SQL database with one command?   I have this command that will get me all the 20 or so drop statements, but how can I run all of those drop statements from this "result set"?

```
select * from vw_drop_idnex;
```

Another variation that gives me the same list is:

```
SELECT  'DROP INDEX ' + ix.Name + ' ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(ID)  AS QUERYLIST
FROM  sysindexes ix
WHERE   ix.Name IS NOT null and ix.Name like '%pre_%'
```

I tried to do "exec(select cmd from vw_drop_idnex)" and it didn't work.  I am looking for something that works like a for loop and runs the queries one by one.

### -----------------------

With Rob Farleys help, final draft of the script is:

```
declare @ltr nvarchar(1024);
SELECT @ltr = ( select 'alter table '+o.name+' drop constraint '+i.name+';'
  from sys.indexes i join sys.objects o on  i.object_id=o.object_id
  where o.type<>'S' and is_primary_key=1
  FOR xml path('') );
exec sp_executesql @ltr;

declare @qry nvarchar(1024);
select @qry = (select 'drop index '+o.name+'.'+i.name+';'
  from sys.indexes i join sys.objects o on  i.object_id=o.object_id
  where o.type<>'S' and is_primary_key<>1 and index_id>0
for xml path(''));
exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: I think it's interesting that you added " AS QUERYLIST", when actually the answer you need shouldn't use that - as FOR XML PATH('') will concatenate strings in unnamed columns better (ie, without tags).

Comment: Cool - you've got it sorted. I was basing my stuff on your sysindexes query, since most people don't have a copy of your 'vw_drop_idnex'.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're very close.

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max);
select @qry = 
(SELECT  'DROP INDEX ' + quotename(ix.name) + ' ON ' + quotename(object_schema_name(object_id)) + '.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) + '; '
FROM  sys.indexes ix
WHERE   ix.Name IS NOT null and ix.Name like '%prefix_%'
for xml path(''));
exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  i knew about that method but i was hoping for something that didnt require declaring a variable.  i can make it work though.

Comment: Also worth mentioning... you should probably consider the quotename function around your names, in case they have spaces in them.

Comment: its not quite working.  i get a message that says: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to name that column still. Make sure you don't have "AS QUERYLIST" or anything in there. While debugging, replace the line "exec sp_executesql @qry" with "select @qry" to see what you're about to run. It should become more obvious then.

Comment: your last comment helped a LOT!  the problem was that I needed a semi-colon at the end of each sql statement in the result set.   also, this method doesn't get me the corresponding "alter table... drop contraint..." query that I need in order to drop indexes.   the vw_drop_idnex stored procedure that I mentioned at the top of my question was giving me that.  any idea?

Comment: If I manually remove the offending constraint the solution works.  Now I just need to figure out how to get the drop constraint statement that will allow me to drop the indexes.

Comment: Given this is ~3 years later, i used this and fixed it by changing the select like to read: `SELECT  'DROP INDEX [' + ix.name + '] ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(ID) + '; '` - I have indexes that include the `+` sign and requires the actual index name to be delimited like `[MY INDEX+]`. Other symbols and white space will require the same (Maybe the aforementioned `<` symbol included?)

Comment: I used the above solution but it only deleted a quarter of my indexes. The solution here worked better: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3441/script-out-all-sql-server-indexes-in-a-database-using-tsql/

Comment: How to modify this script to delete indexes on the remote database (dbname will pass as parameter)?

Comment: The change would be quite significant, because you’d need to have both the query (to list the indexes) and the conmand (to drop the indexes) on the remote database. And a database name can’t be passed as a parameter, so you might be better off putting this into a file and then running it against the appropriate database using sqlcmd or invoke-sqlcmd.

Comment: In case your table name is a keyword (like Statistics in my instance), the third line should be altered to: `(SELECT 'DROP INDEX [' + ix.name + '] ON [' + OBJECT_NAME(ID) + ']; '`.

Answer (score 11):

this worked for me
we skip sys indexes and for constraints

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max);
select @qry = (

    select  'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name='''+ i.name +''' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(''['+s.name+'].['+o.name+']''))      drop index ['+i.name+'] ON ['+s.name+'].['+o.name+'];  '
    from sys.indexes i 
        inner join sys.objects o on  i.object_id=o.object_id
        inner join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where o.type<>'S' and is_primary_key<>1 and index_id>0
    and s.name!='sys' and s.name!='sys' and is_unique_constraint=0
for xml path(''));

exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Answer (score 6):

From: [Stephen Hill's Bloggie](http://refactormycode.com/codes/522-drop-all-indexes-in-sql-server)

```
DECLARE @indexName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE [indexes] CURSOR FOR

        SELECT          [sysindexes].[name] AS [Index],
                        [sysobjects].[name] AS [Table]

        FROM            [sysindexes]

        INNER JOIN      [sysobjects]
        ON              [sysindexes].[id] = [sysobjects].[id]

        WHERE           [sysindexes].[name] IS NOT NULL 
        AND             [sysobjects].[type] = 'U'
        --AND               [sysindexes].[indid] > 1

OPEN [indexes]

FETCH NEXT FROM [indexes] INTO @indexName, @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        --PRINT 'DROP INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @tableName + ']'
        Exec ('DROP INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @tableName + ']')

        FETCH NEXT FROM [indexes] INTO @indexName, @tableName
END

CLOSE           [indexes]
DEALLOCATE      [indexes]

GO
```

Comment: Excellent! It even includes a commented out print line for testing :)

Comment: This will fail if there is one constraint on the table since those can only be dropoped using `DROP CONSTRAINT`, not `DROP INDEX`

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers quite suited my needs.

I needed one that will also drop indexes that backup unique or primary constraints (except if these can't be dropped as they back up a foreign key)

```
DECLARE @SqlScript NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @SqlScript = 
(
SELECT 
'
BEGIN TRY
'+ CASE WHEN 1 IN (i.is_primary_key, i.is_unique_constraint) THEN
 '
 ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)  + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ';'
else
 '
 DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name)  + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
 END+'

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
RAISERROR(''Could not drop %s on table %s'', 0,1, ' + QUOTENAME(i.name, '''') + ', ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ')
END CATCH
'
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'NONCLUSTERED' )
ORDER BY t.object_id, i.index_id DESC
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

--Return script that will be run 
SELECT @SqlScript AS [processing-instruction(x)]
FOR XML PATH('');

EXEC (@SqlScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor improvements to the accepted answer that I had to make in my own case, mostly to account for schemas:

```
declare @qry nvarchar(4000);
select @qry = (select 'drop index ['+s.name+'].['+o.name+'].['+i.name+'];'
  from sys.indexes i join sys.objects o on i.object_id=o.object_id join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id=s.schema_id
  where o.type<>'S' and is_primary_key<>1 and index_id>0 and s.name<>'sys'
for xml path(''));
exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Also: In my case it couldn't run in one go because the script becomes longer than 4000 characters. The only way I could think of to deal with that was to put a "top 20" on the inner select and execute it multiple times.

Comment: To get round the character count limitation, use `nvarchar(max)` as the datatype for `@qry` if you are on SQL 2005 or later.

Comment: @EdHarper I tried that and it told me that type could be used as a variable. I'm on 2008R2 (Express).

Comment: Use varchar not nvarchar and you get 8000 chars instead of 4000

Answer (score 1):

The "Final Draft" that OP posts as part of his question errors out if there are already zero indexes on any table in the DB. I needed to fix that.

Also, I wanted more control over the process than dropping all indexes on **all** tables, so I wrote the following stored proc to do it one table at a time:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DropAllIndexesOnTable]

@TableName varchar(1000)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @DropCommand1 nvarchar(4000)
   DECLARE @DropCommand2 nvarchar(4000)

--Create Temp Table to hold the names and table names of all Clustered Indexes
    SELECT o.name AS TableName, i.name AS IndexName
      INTO #AllClustered
      FROM sys.indexes i 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id=o.object_id
     WHERE o.type <> 'S'
       AND is_primary_key = 1

--Create Temp Table to hold the names and table names of all NonClustered Indexes
    SELECT o.name AS TableName, i.name AS IndexName
      INTO #AllNonClustered
      FROM sys.indexes i 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id=o.object_id
     WHERE o.type <> 'S'
       AND is_primary_key <> 1 
       AND index_id > 0

--Create DROP CONSTRAINT command for the Primary Key Constraint if there is one
    SELECT @DropCommand1 = ( SELECT 'ALTER TABLE dbo.['+ TableName +'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+ IndexName +'];'
                               FROM #AllClustered
                              WHERE TableName = @TableName
                                FOR xml path('') ); 

--Create DROP INDEX command for the indexes on the table if there are any 
    SELECT @DropCommand2 = ( SELECT 'DROP INDEX [' + IndexName + '] ON dbo.['+ TableName +'];'
                               FROM #AllNonClustered
                              WHERE TableName = @TableName
                                FOR xml path('') );

        IF (@DropCommand1 IS NULL AND @DropCommand2 IS NULL) PRINT 'No action taken, zero indexes found on table ' + @TableName
        IF @DropCommand1 IS NOT NULL EXEC sp_executesql @DropCommand1
        IF @DropCommand2 IS NOT NULL EXEC sp_executesql @DropCommand2

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllClustered
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllNonClustered

END
GO
```

I cycle through the specific tables in my DB which I want to drop indexes on using a loop,  and I drop the indexes by calling this proc with the table name, and recreate better ones right after. This way, only one table at a time has no indexes.

The reason I do this and the number of tables I do it on would make your head spin, but I definitely needed a proc like this!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  'DROP INDEX [' + IX.NAME + '] ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(IX.OBJECT_ID) + '; '
FROM  SYS.INDEXES IX
  JOIN SYS.OBJECTS O ON  IX.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS S ON O.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE 
  IX.NAME IS NOT NULL 
  AND O.TYPE <> 'S' 
  AND IS_PRIMARY_KEY <> 1 
  AND INDEX_ID > 0
  AND S.NAME != 'SYS' AND S.NAME!= 'SYS' AND IS_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT = 0
```

Modify conditions according to your needs

If u want to delete PK constraints, you will get this message if you try to drop index:

> An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index... It is being used for PRIMARY KEY constraint enforcement.

Then, use this...

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + O.NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT  ' + IX.NAME + '; '
FROM  SYS.INDEXES IX
  JOIN SYS.OBJECTS O ON  IX.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS S ON O.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE 
  IX.NAME IS NOT NULL 
  AND O.TYPE <> 'S' 
  AND INDEX_ID > 0
  AND S.NAME != 'SYS' AND S.NAME!= 'SYS'
```