# Scandinavian letter error, drop index from table?

Tags: mysql

How to DROP INDEX from entire table at mysql ? 

My code:
`DROP INDEX`päättä`ON data`
As result I get error:
`#1091 - Can't DROP 'pÃ¤Ã¤ttÃ¤'; check that column/key exists`

Solution would be remove all indexes from entire table ?
Does Mysql have it's own letters for Ä and Ö.

Comment: Always use plain english

Comment: Yea, I think I will rename all the scandinavian letters away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paavo Doe You can get the indexes with

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `table`
```

You can drop more than one index in one query, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX first, DROP INDEX second, DROP INDEX third
```

if you want delete indexing from entire database these link will help you: [[Delete all indexes of specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741054/delete-all-indexes-of-specific-database]) OR [[How can I drop all indexes in a SQL database with one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344401/how-can-i-drop-all-indexes-in-a-sql-database-with-one-command])

Comment: Need to check if Mysql Workbench has button for un-indexing. when trying un-index I get Getting that #1091 - Can't DROP 'pÃ¤Ã¤ttÃ¤'; check that column/key exists error

Comment: @Paavo Doe I added same index (**pÃ¤Ã¤ttÃ¤**) as you mentioned. Also deleted from above mentioned query. Its working fine. May be you are doing some mistake in it.

Comment: Thank you! I really dont know what I kept doing wrong but now got this working thanks.